# Where does the spark come from? (an embedded system circuit)

Tags: microcontroller, esd, reliability

We are developing an embedded system product. As an inexperienced engineer, I am really scratching my head to make our product reliable: temperature, ESD and etc..

The following diagram shows my circuit:

[image]
Yesterday I connected one pin of MCU with 3.3V(SELECTION port, which is a two pin 2.54mm header) using a jumper, when MCU is on, and sparks appears at the connection. After that, our MCU stopped working normally.

[image]

Where are the sparks from?

- Could connecting 3.3V with pin pulling down to ground cause sparks?
- I heard that sparks can only be generated at high voltage ESD, say over 8kV.
- I tend to think the sparks are not caused by ESD, since the same operation has been done multiple times during the same hour before the sparks appear.

**For the code part**

Library: STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver

```
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_12; // we are going to use PB6 and PB7
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;           // set pins to alternate function
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;      // set GPIO speed
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD;         // set output to open drain --> the line has to be only pulled low, not driven high
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;           // enable pull up resistors
GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);     //Init PC10, PC12

GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2;
GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);     //Init PD2
```

Comment: If the jumper is only used to set the pin high I would strongly recommend putting a 1 kOhm resistor in series between 3V3 and jumper pin 1. The voltage divider is neglible and it will safeguard you from similar situations in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sparks can be created by any number of things.  Certainly by high voltage; this can be seen when you touch a doorknob after walking across carpet on a dry day :)

In your case, though, I don't believe the spark was caused by this mechanism.  Instead, if your input pin was configured as a pull-down, you created a dead short between your 3.3V supply and the ground.  This dead short caused a high amount of current to flow, which literally melted/vaporized a piece of the circuit.  This vaporized material is what you saw as a "spark".

When using the circuit in your diagram the input pin must always be configured as high-impedance ("Hi-Z").  This prevents any significant current from flowing into (or out of) the pin.

Please be clear about the "pulling to ground" terminology.  That phrase is sometimes used as you used it, that is, when the pin is set low (or being "pulled" or "driven" low).  However, it is also used when referring to pull-up or pull-down resistors.  With pull-up (or pull-down) resistors, the pin is pulled high (or low) *through a large resistance*.  This resistor limits current, preventing circuit damage.

Pull-up (or pull-down) resistors are necessary for the circuit that you show. You have done it correctly with R314. These can be actual discrete components (as you used), or most microcontroller outputs can be configured to use internal pull-ups (or pull-downs).

---

By the way, any time you make or break an electrical connection there is a likelihood of some small spark. Imagine two conductors in the air separated by 1 cm.  It would take approximately 31 kV to cause a spark.  If they were only 0.5 cm apart, it would take around 17 kV.  As you can see, the breakdown voltage is dependent on the distance.

When you connect two conductors together, you are decreasing the separation distance until they actually contact.  Eventually a spark will happen, although it is often too small to detect.  It's not a problem unless the spark is fairly high-energy.

Interestingly, most ESD damage is done without noticeable sparking.  Perhaps this is because people don't realize that it's happening and so they don't correct it until it's too late...

---

**Edit**:

Thanks for posting your code.  **It looks correct**, although there are a few things that cause worry. For example, your comments don't match what is actually happening.  Are you intending to use PC10 and PC12 (as per the code) or PB6 and PB7 (as per the comments)?

Another problem is that you're setting the output configuration to Open Drain.  This shouldn't actually matter, since the output configuration is ignored when the pin is set to an input.  But, if you were experimenting and set it to Output, then it would cause this type of failure.

For your info, you have correctly set the pin as a digital input (implying high impedance) with this command: `GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;`

Once the pin has been set as an input, certain parameters are ignored and are usually omitted from your code.  In this case, you may choose to delete these lines:

```
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply. Would configuring the input pin as high-Z solve the problem? Or some protection else shall be performed?

Comment: Yes, the solution is to configure the pin as a high-impedance digital input.  Which MCU are you using?  Different companies use different terms but it is common to simply say "digital input".  This implies high-impedance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I have three more doubts. 1. Why a dead short would be created if the pin is configured as pull down, since there is a pull down resistor inside MCU?
2. I am using a STM32-F4, I could not find a High-Z option for the input pin. And in my application, the pin is configured as no pull-up or pull-down resistors.
3. I am not sure if I understood your comments on "pulling down" correctly. In my circuit, pull down means the pin is pulled down by R314(100k), which is shown in the schematic.

Comment: Can I have your comments? @bitsmack

Comment: @richieqianle Sorry for the delay. Please edit your question with the following info: 1. Which libraries are you using for your STM32F4?  Might be "Cube", HAL, "Standard Peripheral Library (SPL)", etc. 2. Please show the code you use to configure the pin. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have modified the post. Could you have a look? Thanks!

Comment: @richieqianle Hmm, your code and circuit both look correct.  Please see the additions to my answer. I hope something is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found a very good comment from Jan Dorniak, which is: "If the jumper is only used to set the pin high I would strongly recommend putting a 1 kOhm resistor in series between 3V3 and jumper pin 1. The voltage divider is neglible and it will safeguard you from similar situations in the future." Could you please put it in your answer as well?